# JQuery doesn't work at times and Im not sure why

Tags: jquery

I'm still new to JQuery, because I keep having weird issues like this with no error and that make no sense.  It's not something I can google, though I have and I'm getting no where.   So please tell me what I'm missing.   I can make this work on jsfiddle, but fails everywhere else.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
{
 var intID = null;
}

$('[delbtn]').click( function() {
 var msg = $('[delbtn]').attr("msg");
 $('#PromptDialog').html(msg);
 $('#PromptDialog').dialog( {
      title: "Delete Prompt",
      autoOpen: true,
      show: "blind",
      hide: "explode",
      modal: true,
      width: "400px",
   resizable: false,
     buttons: [
      {
        text: "Yes",
        class: "yesClass",
        click: function () {
         $('#resposneText').html('Yes was clicked');
          $('#PromptDialog').dialog('close');
          clearTimeout(intID);
        }
      },
      {
        text: "No",
        class: "noClass",
        click: function () {
         $('#resposneText').html('No was clicked');
          $('#PromptDialog').dialog('close');
          clearTimeout(intID);
        }
      }],
   open: function(event, ui) {
          intID = setTimeout(function(){
              $('#PromptDialog').dialog('close');
          }, 10000);
      }
  });
});

$('#DeleteButton').click( function() {
 var msg = $('#DeleteButton').attr("msg");
 $('#PromptDialog').html(msg);
 $('#PromptDialog').dialog( {
      title: "Delete Prompt",
      autoOpen: true,
      show: "blind",
      hide: "explode",
      modal: true,
      width: "400px",
   resizable: false,
     buttons: [
      {
        text: "Yes",
        class: "yesClass",
        click: function () {
         $('#resposneText').html('Yes was clicked');
          $('#PromptDialog').dialog('close');
          clearTimeout(intID);
        }
      },
      {
        text: "No",
        class: "noClass",
        click: function () {
         $('#resposneText').html('No was clicked');
          $('#PromptDialog').dialog('close');
          clearTimeout(intID);
        }
      }],
   open: function(event, ui) {
          intID = setTimeout(function(){
              $('#PromptDialog').dialog('close');
          }, 10000);
      }
  });
});
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 10px;
}

input {
  margin: 20px;
  display: block;
}

#PromptDialog {
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.ui-dialog, .ui-dialog-title {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.ui-dialog-titlebar-close
{
  display:none;
}

.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane
{
  text-align: center;
  background: red;
}

.ui-widget-header, .ui-state-default {
  background:#b9cd6d;
  border: 1px solid #b9cd6d;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.ui-dialog
{
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
}

.ui-dialog-content
{
  color: #fff;
}

.ui-button.yesClass 
{
    background: green;
    color: #000;
}

.ui-button.noClass 
{
    background: green;
    color: #fff;
} 
 
.ui-button.noClass.ui-state-hover,
.ui-button.noClass.ui-state-active,
.ui-button.yesClass.ui-state-hover,
.ui-button.yesClass.ui-state-active
{
    background: red;
    color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="PromptDialog" style="display:none;"></div>
<input type="button" id="DeleteButton" msg="Are you sure you want to delete it?" value="Delete This">
<input type="button" id="DeleteButton2" delbtn="1" msg="Wait, What ??" value="Delete This">
<div id="resposneText"></div>
```

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/29os3n6e/)

Comment: where do you have the js? on doc ready? on load? somewhere else?

Comment: It works on jsFiddle because by default they wrap your JavaScript in a window.load handler. If you're not also doing that, or not using document.ready, or not loading your JS at the end of the page, then you're probably running it too early

Comment: My actual code has the JavaScript in a different file and is at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Have you run your code with the dev tools console open to see if there are errors when it doesn't work properly?

Comment: Yes..  Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (question.js:8)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLInputElement.i (jquery.min.js:3)

Comment: Do you define a dialog function somewhere? Or are you including jQuery UI along with jQuery?

Comment: @j08691, THANK YOU!!!   I thought that was part of JQuery, didn't realize I needed a different JS for that..   Provide that answer and I"ll give it to you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your errors refer to a dialog() function, but jQuery doesn't have one, you need to also include after jquery, jquery UI.

Comment: Thank you..   That was the trick..   Not sure who was Down arrowing my question, they obviously didn't know the answer, but like to bash someone else that asked the question..

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned a jQuery dialog error in a previous comment, it looks like you do not have jquery UI included in your code. Add this after jQuery to ffix that error:

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Documentation for dialog: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: The Javascript is in it's own JS file.   The load is from the bottom of the page.

Comment: Is your site built with WordPress or any other CMS?

Comment: I think i've worked it out, i will updfate my answer

Comment: Yea, j08691 provided that 4 min before you and it was the problem.   He posted it in comments and I was searching to figure that out.   Only reason I'm giving it to him, but will get you an Up for points..   Thanks..